# Can I install winXP with an virtual disk image?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, windows-installation

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Install winXP onto a virtualbox machine.

I will then obtain a copy of winXP virtual disk file, could be vdi or some other format.

Map the vdi into a physical harddrive.

Plug in the harddrive to a physical computer.

Expect the system to boot into the winxp, and start from there, presumably with tons of driver installation.

Will this work?

If so can someone please also recommend a mapping tool for me to map the virtual hd file onto the physical drive?

Comment: You'd probably need hardware at least 7 years old too, to have any hope of finding drivers.

Comment: Back in XP days, if I remember correctly, when XP HDD was ported to another computer with a different motherboard XP would attempt to boot but would simply crash. even Safe Mode would not work. There were some unreliable workarounds, but back then I would prefer to do a clean install of XP on another PC and restore my data from backup. What is the target hardware where you want to port XP HDD? Is this for fun or are you trying to solve any problem?  Continued...

Comment: ..Continued. To give it a try, connect physical disk to XP VM. Use any XP supported Disk Cloning App to clone XP VM to Physical Disk. Disconnect the physical disk and see if it boots on target HW. I am almost sure it will result into BSOD and you may have very less options to fix it I believe. More specifically if it's any HW developed in last few years.

Comment: Acronis with Universal Restore could do this. It could make a clone that would boot on 'anything'. I've no idea how great a timescale in hardware that would be expected to cover. Back in the XP days it 'just worked' but I haven't tried it in many years.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's a good piece of info. OP should try that. I hope it can still run on XP, else OP will have to use Windows 10 VM and then connect XP VHD and Physical disk to it as secondary disks and see if they can clone from VHD to HDD. Modern boards no longer offer IDE mode in Firmware. In absence of AHCI Drivers XP is likely to crash. There were some ways I guess to inject AHCI drivers into XP. Hope Acronis can take care of such differences.

Answer (score 0):

XP is so long out of support that you may find difficulties doing this. Also VMware Workstation / Converter is another approach.

**(1) Build your own XP machine. This works.**

I have posted a method below, but it may also be necessary to get an XP disk (your own or eBay), build a virtual machine (that will work) and copy the data you need into this machine.

**(2) Try to convert your existing machine. May not work.**

For Virtual Box, please look at this article:

[Convert XP to VBOX](https://akhpark.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/converting-physical-windows-xp-system-to-virtual-system/)

You will need software from Microsoft SysInternals.

> Convert the physical system to virtual system. I used Disk2vhd utility
> by sysinternal. You run this utility on the physical Windows XP
> machine. Make sure to uncheck use Vhdx option.

====

> Download Virtualbox and install on the Windows 7/8 system. Before I
> create a new machine, I like to change the Default Machine Folder. By
> default the machine information are stored in the individual user
> folder. I change them to c:\VirtualBox so all users will see the
> virtual machine no matter who they are logged in as. Go to File –>
> Preferences –> General to change the Default Machine Folder option.
> You will also need to add an environment variable (System Variable)
> VBOX_USER_HOME with the value c:\VirtualBox, so all users can have
> access to the VM.

=====

> Create a new VM. When it asks for the Hard Drive, you choose Use an
> existing virtual hard drive file option. Then you browse and look for
> the vhd file you created on step 1.
>
> Start the machine. You now have virtual copy of the physical system.

Comment: Hello John, I'm pretty sure you have got the opposite of the idea.

Comment: You CAN get XP going the two ways I suggested. It will take a bit of time, but it will work.